# Media Server Solution

Tags: media-center

i am currently using Windows Home Server to make use of it's media center capabilities, however, it's a pain that it's designed to run headless, and i don't like the Windows server 2003 OS, as it's not widely supported by some of my media devices.

I want to set up a media server that can be accessed via my PS3, Xbox, a few machines in the house, and hopefully my iPhone.

I also want the media server connected directly to my TV.

I would think there is some good software out there that will do this magically :)

any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say Windows 7 to be honest. It has great media center capabilities as well as streaming to Xbox and other devices.

The network sharing center will allow for ease of setup as well.

Answer (score 1):

I use Mac Mini's with [Twonky Media Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TwonkyMedia_server), works fine for me and may hit all your requirements, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really say what your media devices are, or what you want your media server to do?

If you just want to be able to stream media to the (PS3, XBox, etc) then by far the easiest solution would be to install a better media server, that can handle multiple formats like either TwonkyMedia or TVersity onto your existing Home Server.

If you want to do things like recording and playing back TV, then you probably want something based on Windows Media Centre, like a Windows 7 based machine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to consider the [Cisco/Linksys NMH-300](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0028N6VMI) with Twonky software on board?